# Hook on widget context plugin to add custom context for widget

Tags: plugins, widgets, hooks

I have been using the **widget context** plugin to manage the widgets in my site. There are almost 100's in number of widgets. Some are displayed on some page or category or url other are not. It was working fine until now but due to this new requirement I am thinking twice about the Plugin.

In this particular case, a widget "News" was being showed in all post that was categorized as "News". By using **Target by url**

```
news/*
```

But now the requirement is so that I have to show the widget in all post where the sub category is marked as news.

Now for this I need a help. Any Idea will be appreciate.

Comment: Did you try adding the new subcategories, including the parent, on each line? Like so: news <br>
news/* <br> news/subcat<br>
news/subcat/*

Comment: In my case let us suppose we have two parent category 1. LocalNews 2. Sports. Generally article on localnews will have url structure like /localnews/*
And article on sports will have url structure like /sports/*.
But some time there will be local sport even which has both local news and sports as its category. In such case I am not able to map widget context using url.